# Sorting a Hashmap with a Object as Key and a Integer as Value

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have a Hashmap which contains an object Customer as a Key and an integer "number of products" as a Value.

I want to get the customer object with the lowest amount of products out of this hashmap.

I've tried 2 ways by using a stream, but it always seem that I get a random object and not the object with the lowest int value.

Can anyone help?

```
Map<Customer, Integer> customerMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (Customer customer:customers) {
        customerMap.put(customer, customer.getProducts().size());
    }

customerMap.entrySet().stream()
  .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
  .findFirst().get().getKey()

customerMap.entrySet().stream()
  .min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Integer::compareTo))
  .get().getKey()
```

Comment: "using a lambda expression" You are not using any lambda expressions. You are using Streams and a method reference.

Comment: True, but I want to solve this problem with a lambda expression, but I don't know how.

Comment: So step 1 would be to learn what a lambda expression is, then actually write one.

Comment: @Winds99t When I test your code it returns the correct Customer with both stream expressions

Comment: If the only purpose of the map is to access the number of products I would skip the map and sort the customer objects itself.

Comment: What does this problem have to do with sorting? You just want to get the smallest value and for that sorting is not needed. As a side node, HashMap isn't an ordered collection so we can't really talk about sorting it in any way.

Comment: How about a SortedMap (TreeMap) instead ?
Then the contents are sorted by default and there are methods for extracting the minimum/maximum entries. Please see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have to sort your collection if you just want to find the key with the smallest value.

If you are sure you will only have a single key with the smallest value (there might be more), then you can do this:

```
Customer customerWithSmallestValue = map.entrySet().stream()
                                        .min(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue))
                                        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                                        .get();
```

or alternatively

```
Customer customerWithSmallestValue = map.entrySet().stream()
                                        .min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Integer::compareTo))
                                        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                                        .get();
```

> Please note that these two options will give you the **last found result** in case there are more than just one key having the smallest value in the map.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your problem, when I test your code it returns the correct `Customer` with both streams

2 other ways to get the result without using `Map` would be:

1 - Sorting the customer list on its `products` list size, and taking the first one: (as Maia pointed)

```
customers.sort(Comparator.comparing(cu -> cu.getProducts().size()));
Customer c = customers.get(0);
```

2 - Using a classic `for` loop:

```
Customer c = customers.get(0);
for(Customer cu : customers) {
    if(cu.getProducts().size() < c.getProducts().size())
        c = cu;
}
```